# CDK Wont add tags to ELB listener (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm currently trying to add Tags to an ELBs listener via CDK, I can do this on the console UI however even when I run CDK synth I see that the tags arent necessarily added, however this works when adding them directly to the ELB and only fails for the listener, documentation didn't really help to explain this issue.

Example code below.

```
ApplicationListener listener = applicationLoadBalancer.addListener(ELB_LISTENER_REF_NAME, BaseApplicationListenerProps
    .builder()
    .protocol(ApplicationProtocol.HTTP)
    .port(port)
    .defaultAction(ListenerAction.fixedResponse(200, FixedResponseOptions.builder()
    .messageBody("OK")
    .contentType("text/plain")
    .build()))
    .build());

Tags.of(listener).add("env", ENVIRONMENT);
Tags.of(listener).add("elb-listener-name", ELB_LISTENER_REF_NAME);
Tags.of(listener).add("elb-port", port.toString());
```

Tags to be added to the ELB Listener